# How can I create a list of factors of a number?

Tags: list, prolog, numbers, factors

I want to create a function factoring that takes a number and returns a list of all of its factors in ascending order. My current issue is that some factors repeat themselves and others do not show up at all

`factors(X,121)` returns `[11,11,1]` instead of just `[11]`
`factors(X,16)` returns `[2,2,2,1]` instead of `[2,4,8]`

```
factors([1],1):- !.
factors([X|T], B):- B > 0,
    between(2,B,X),
    I is B // X, (B mod X) =:= 0,
    factors(T,I),!.
```

Expected behavior is for `factors(A,16)` to return the list `[2,4,8]`.

1 and the target number are not included in the list. The 1 is already being handled in the first statement. I would like to use the most basic syntax possible so that I can become more familiar with how Prolog works.

Comment: I believe the correct terminology is *divisors*. You are looking for all *divisors* of a number N. And, if you exclude 1 and N then you want only *proper divisors*.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk —  The O.P. is asking for _factors_: for any given _N_, there exists an infinite number of divisors.

Comment: @NicholasCarey: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor

Comment: For any division expression, X ÷ Y, X is the dividend and Y the divisor. There is no restriction on division that I'm aware of that either X or Y be integer/whole/natural numbers, or for that matter, even real numbers. Given φ ÷ 5_i_ : ɸ is still the dividend and 5_i_ the divisor.

Answer (score 1):

Using the trial division algorithm for factoring an integer *N*, the upper limit on what needs to be tried is the square root of *N*: consider a perfect square like 81. Its factors are:

- 1 x 81
- 3 x 27
- 9 x 9

And any values higher than `sqrt(81)` (9) are the quotient from integer division of 81 by a value less than or equal to 9.

So... factoring a number is easy:

```
factor(N,F) :-
    integer(N),
    N >= 0 ,
    L is floor(sqrt(N)) ,
    between(1,L,F1) ,
    div_rem(N,F1,F2,0) ,
    unique_factors(F1,F2,F)
    .
    
div_rem(X,Y,Q,R) :-
    Q is X div Y ,
    R is X mod Y
    .

unique_factors(A,B,A) :- A \= B .
unique_factors(_,B,B) .
```

To collect all the factors is even easier:

```
factors(N,Fs) :- findall(F, factor(N,F), F0), sort(F0,Fs).
```

One should note here, that that `sort/2` removes duplicates and turns the unsorted list into, strictly speaking, an ordered *set*.
See it in the playground: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/QuUnomwk.pl

If you want to remove 1 and `N` from the list of factors, simply change

```
between(1,L,F1)
```

to

```
between(2,L,F1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you are mixing up backtracking and recursion. With this code:

```
test(X) :-
    between(2, 5, X).

?- test(Answer).
Answer = 2 ;
Answer = 3 ;
Answer = 4 ;
Answer = 5
```

The code finds one value for X between 2 and 5 and leaves a choicepoint; then when I use `;` to ask it to find another, Prolog backtracks to the choicepoint and finds the next value between 2 and 5.

With your code, you are using `between(2,B,X)` which generates values on backtracking, and at the same time you are doing `I is B // X` to make a new endpoint and then descending into `factors(T, I)` which starts between() from 2 again. And you cut `!` to discard choicepoints, so backtracking can never come back to find the rest of the numbers up to the earlier `B`, either. That's where your `[2, 2, 2` is coming from, I think.

You can do it either way, as Nicholas Carey answers with `between()` and then using `findall` to generate all the backtracking answers. Or by using recursion:

```
n_factors(N, F) :-
    n_factors(N, 1, F).

n_factors(Num, Num, [1]).  % Base case.

n_factors(Num, Counter, [H|T]) :- % Case where Counter is a factor
    0 =:= Num mod Counter,
    H is Num div Counter,
    succ(Counter, Cnext),
    n_factors(Num, Cnext, T).

n_factors(Num, Counter, T) :- % Case where Counter is NOT a factor
    0 =\= Num mod Counter,
    succ(Counter, Cnext),
    n_factors(Num, Cnext, T).
```

e.g.

```
?- time(n_factors(121, Factors)).
482 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (100% CPU, 1852400 Lips)
Factors = [121, 11, 1]

?- time(n_factors(1048576, F)).
4,194,302 inferences, 0.785 CPU in 0.785 seconds (100% CPU, 5344086 Lips)
F = [1048576, 524288, 262144, 131072, 65536, 32768, 16384, 8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

(You may want to compare `time()` and see just how much quicker it is to do stop counting at the square root of N, as the other answer does).

Or rewrite your approach to